# How do I create a one time use startup script on Linux - Centos 6.x

Tags: linux, script, centos, shell-script

I want to set a script that will only run one time on a Centos 6.x box and then never run again, since it's going to set some system options based on hardware and then it's all set.

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/questions/148341/linux-schedule-command-to-run-once-after-reboot-runonce-equivalent for some suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers over on Server Fault are very good. For an even simpler version you could either i) just run the script yourself once. or ii) add a `@reboot` cron and then delete it:

```
echo "@reboot root NAME.sh && sed -i '/NAME/d' /etc/crontab" >> /etc/crontab
```